# How to keep the same velocity after bumping into things ? (Unity 2D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics, physics

My game (2D Top-Down view) is about a tank that fires bouncing bullets. Those bullets have infinite bounces and keep the same velocity after bouncing. It works fine with static objects, however it doesn't keep the same velocity with moving objects : the bullet can push things, but will slow and I don't know how to remove the slow.

Here is a tweet where you can see the bullets slow down after touching some objects :
https://twitter.com/TurboDevTeam/status/1350751139508215808?s=20

Edit :
Here are the parameters of the bullet :

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried adding a material with 1 of bounciness?

Comment: @Leoverload There is a material like that on the bullet. I also tried to apply this material to the rest of the objects, but the result was the same.

Comment: How are your friction and drag values set?

Comment: @Jox Check Be sure that on bullet physics material is Bounce combine set on maximum and bounciness is set to 1.

Comment: @Aboud I updated the post and added de physics materials

Comment: What is your settings for `Physics2D -> Velocity Threshold`? See [Physics 2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Physics2DManager.html) `Velocity Threshold Set the threshold for elastic collisions
. Unity treats collisions with a relative velocity lower than this value as inelastic collisions (that is, the colliding GameObjects do not bounce off each other).` .. could this be the issue? And in particular for any bouncing physics .. if the object you hit is moving away from you, so in the same bullet direction, it will not bounce much but slow down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

derHugo's comment is on point: since the cars move when hit, they absorb part of the energy.

I've set up a minimal example to demonstrate.

The ball has a `CircleCollider2D` and a `Rigidbody2D` with `Linear Drag = 0` and a material with `Friction = 0` and `Bounciness = 1`.
The walls have a `BoxCollider2D` and a `Rigidbody2D`. Gravity is disabled.

For the first test, the wall `Rigidbody2D` is set to `Static`.

[image: Test 1, Static Wall]

For the second test, the wall `Rigidbody2D` is set to `Dynamic`, with `Mass = 10` and `Linear Drag = 1`.

[image: Test 2, Dynamic Wall]

In order to keep it bouncing forever in this case, you must code the bounciness by yourself. First remove the Physics Material or set the bounciness to 0, to make sure the Physics Engine is not simulating it.

Then, create a script for the bullet:

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector2 lastVelocity;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        lastVelocity = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.Reflect(lastVelocity, collision.contacts[0].normal);
    }
}
```

(Please note that you should use `GetComponent` carefully, maybe calling it only once on Start and saving a reference, I didn't do it to keep a minimal sample.)

The idea here is to take the velocity right before the collision and invert it. However, if you take the `Rigidbody2D` velocity on `OnCollisionEnter`, it's already the updated value. So you must store the value in `FixedUpdate`, since the next is only called after the `OnCollisionEnter` method.
Then, you use `Vector2.Reflect` to reflect the incoming velocity by the collision normal.

[image: Test 3, Dynamic Wall, Custom Bounce]

`Vector2.Reflect` results are valid in 2D:

[image: Test 4, Dynamic Wall, Custom Bounce, 2D]

Comment: That is really cool, Thank you ! But I tried it : most of the time it works just perfectly, but I noticed if the bullet hits some kind of corners or small/light objects in my game, the velocity still reduces

Comment: I added a gif so you can see what happens

Comment: Try printing the `lastVelocity` magnitude every `FixedUpdate` to debug, it should be near constant. Small differences might happen due to numeric issues I guess, check if that's the case. If so, scale the new velocity so it's magnitude matches the last one, to make sure it remains constant.

Comment: Yes it is the case, the magnitude goes from 10 to 4. Thanks a lot I managed to scale the velocity in fixed update with your help.